# angular publish project network error

Tags: javascript, angular, publish

Hello i have an angular 4 project and i wanted to publish on my web site

i used these steps

- ng build
- opened dist file
- open ftp server
- i put all dist file to http_docs\

then i open the web site and look at this error

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

but if i work locally there is no problem

you can check this link neredenekadar.net

i tried in index.html changing base href to ''and '/my/app' and a lot of things but i couldn't

if i go neredenekadar.net/Login

i got this error on the console

GET https://neredenekadar.net/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Login:21 GET https://neredenekadar.net/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Login:22 GET https://neredenekadar.net/styles.bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Login:23 GET https://neredenekadar.net/scripts.bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Login:24 GET https://neredenekadar.net/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Login:25 GET https://neredenekadar.net/main.bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

also i'm using firebase in my project maybe these errors related with firebase i don't know please help me

Comment: start your project from a web server

Comment: what is it mean ?

Comment: now you serve your file as FTP but you should serve it with HTTP

Comment: how can i do it with your way ?

Comment: we are using nginx web server to host the files

Comment: my host is windows should i change this for linux ?

Comment: nop you don't change just server your file from a web server thats all

Answer (score -1):

Change base may start working your application

Change

```
<base href="/my/app/">
```

to

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: i changed but id didnt help